# select query that will filter only the delivered order

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to print the orders using tcpdf. my query runs fine but it reads all the order's statuses including pending whose value is 1 and out for delivery whose value is 3 I want the output to be printed where the status is Delivered whose value is 4. I already tried adding the where status = 4 on my query but there are no output shows.

here's my query below

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, customize_order.id AS customid FROM customize_order LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=customize_order.user_id WHERE order_date  BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ORDER BY order_date DESC");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Are you sure that your data have this result for status = 4 and selected dates?

Comment: Yes in my order table i do have a data wherein the status is 4

Comment: And there are included dates with this status? Could you please show the query with the status?

Comment: I don't understand. You talk about "status" in your question but "status" is not present in your query

Comment: SELECT *, customize_order.id AS customid FROM customize_order LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=customize_order.user_id WHERE order_date AND customize_order.status = 4 BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ORDER BY order_date DESC

Comment: thats my query with the status

Comment: Your query is not right. Try this `SELECT *, customize_order.id AS customid FROM customize_order LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=customize_order.user_id WHERE order_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND customize_order.status = 4 ORDER BY order_date DESC`

Comment: Please tag appropriately. _"I am trying to print the orders using tcpdf"_ - that might well be - but is has absolutely nothing to do with what your question is actually about. It would still be the exact same question, if you weren't creating a PDF ... but decided to manually scrawl the data of the orders onto the wall in crayon. (Tag removed.)

Comment: Pass `$from` and `$to` as arguments to `execute()` and use placeholders in the prepared statement.